# Writing a function in Python

Tags: python, function

I wrote the following function in Python, however it does not work. I tried different colors from the `paint_colors` list and the function only returns `found` if I give `pink` as an input. Moreover, for example if I type `green` as input it returns `not found`, but this color is also in the `paint_colors` list.. Why does my function not work for the other colors?

```
paint_colors = ["pink", "white", "red", "green", "brown", "purple", "blue"]
color_input = input("Enter the color you are looking for:")

def function():
    for color in paint_colors:
        if color == color_input:
            return "found"
        else:
            return "not found"
print(function())
```

Comment: You always return the first time through the loop. You should only return "not found" after the loop has finished.

Comment: The solutions below are correct. However, I am almost certain that, at the very least, you want `color_input` as a parameter of your function, not a global variable (even though these solutions "work"). For example: `def function(color_input):`. That is a more important point than the syntax that the other answers are helping you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to find whether `color_input` is in `paint_colors` is just to say `color_input in paint_colors`:

```
def function():
    if color_input in paint_colors:
        return "found"
    else:
        return "not found"
```

For simple tasks involving a list there's frequently a simpler option than iterating over the entire list!

Answer (score 1):

1. You check only first element in list.
2. Make sure that all variables has same type.

```
def function():
    for color in paint_colors:
        if str(color) == str(color_input):
            return "found"
    return "not found"

paint_colors = ["pink", "white", "red", "green", "brown", "purple", "blue"]
color_input = input("Enter the color you are looking for:")

print(function())
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is

```
def function():
    return "true" if color in paint_colors else "false"
```

Here, `color in paint_colors` is checking if the value `color` is equal to any of the values in the list `paint_colors`, effectively doing the same thing as a `for` loop.